# How to program a TSC Printer (where to put code)?

Tags: printer-control-language

So, I'm a bit unsure about how this works.
I saw this pdf: http://www.tscprinters.com/cms/upload/download_en/TSPL_TSPL2_Programming.pdf
Contains a fairly simple-to-understand guide on how to program TSC Printers using TSPL Language, I see that my printer is on the list of compatible ones (TC210).
Now what I can't seem to find is.. where am I supposed to put this file? I have the printer connected to my pc via usb but I don't see any folder or anything similar where I could upload this files that the guide keeps talking about.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case if you are looking for Java based driver to be used in your client applications, head over to https://github.com/fintrace/tspl2-driver

Answer (score 1):

You may use TSC utility "Printer Management" to download formats, fonts, pictures, etc. (Printer Management > File Manager):
http://www.tscprinters.com/cms/upload/download_en/TPM_2.16.zip